# How to wait for Recaptcha to load in Puppeteer/Pyppeteer?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, automation, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I want to scrape a website and I'm having difficulties with the Recaptcha. I've already figured out a way to solve it but before that method starts I have to make sure Recaptcha is fully loaded, which is what I'm stuck at.
I've tried `page.waitForSelector('#captchaFormPart > td:nth-child(2) > script:nth-child(1)', options={'visible': True})`, I got the selector from inspecting the Recaptcha's box, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha) to automatically solve reCaptcha using [2Captcha](https://2captcha.com/) service.

It will automatically wait until the reCAPTCHA script (if any) has been loaded and initialized.